# Error when installing graphviz on Mac using Homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, graphviz

I am using macOS 11.5.1 Big Sur and I tried to install Graphviz via

```
brew install graphviz
```

but I got an error:

```
Error: python@3.9: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

The version of my Homebrew is

```
Homebrew 3.0.5
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 7ff3c752de; last commit 2021-08-13)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision af069ca1b1; last commit 2021-08-13)
```

I have no idea about the reason. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue, by the following commands.

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Then rerun the brew install:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

It works on my Mac. Just share in case that anyone encounters the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get it to work with homebrew. I read other threads recommending trying with Ports, which I did and failed also, since I got a little farther with Ports, I continue to look and finally found this...

1. Uninstall graphiz if you tried homebrew: `brew uninstall graphviz`
2. Install Ports https://www.macports.org/install.php
3. edit the Ports installation https://www.macports.org/install.php

Edit `opt/etc/macports/sources.conf`, comment out the rsync entry, and add a new entry as follows:

```
#rsync://rsync.macports.org/macports/release/tarballs/ports.tar [default]
https://distfiles.macports.org/ports.tar.gz [default]
```

Run sync in debug mode and watch for the tarball being used instead of rsync:

```
sudo port -d sync
```

4. `sudo port install graphviz`